# How to add a new metamodel to Acceleo

Tags: acceleo

I would like to use Acceleo to tranform [Owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language) files to java classes.

However I do not see the uri for the Owl metamodel in Acceleo.

How does one add a new metamodel template specification to Acceleo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Eclipse is currently loading the plugin containing the Owl metamodel? in the About Eclipse window there should be an 'installation details' button. Click that and then click on the 'plugins' tab. Check there if the plugin you need is loaded. If so you should see the meta-model (double check the uri you are typing).

Comment: I cannot see anything in the plugins tab related to the owl metamodel. I also did a fresh install of Acceleo, and there was no owl metamodel present.

Comment: I don't think Acceleo comes with an implementation of the OWL meta-model. I guessed you had already installed an OWL plugin. I am not an OWL expert but I think you can find something useful here http://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/MOF-Based_Metamodel